# Changing an image's source in Windows phone

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8

I'm developing a metronome application, I made a bunch of images for it to display the rhythm number, but I don't know how tho load the images in the first place if I even need. I tried with this:

```
tactImgList[0] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Assets/Images/1.png"));
```

And so on the rest, but I'm always getting a URI format exception.

What am I doing wrong? I tried to google my problem, but nothing.

Comment: Try to specify the UriKind  `new Uri("Assets/Images/1.png", UriKind.Relative);`

Comment: What is `tactImgList` here..? is it `ImageSource` or `Image` control..? elaborate your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should provide the full path to your file starting with "ms-appx:///".

```
tactImgList[0] = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"ms-appx:///Assets/Images/1.png");
```